# Getting a variable using a variable

Tags: java

How would I get a variable in another class using a variable in the current class? For example: The variable "userclass" Can either be human or alien. Inside my other class ("Cv.java") there are two variables (human, alien) How would I get one of the two variables in Cv.java, while using the "userclass" variable to get it.

Example 2:

userclass = alien

Cv.????

How would I get Cv.alien whilst using "userclass"

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a `Map`.

Comment: Wayyy to many variables in Cv to add them all to a map. It'd take a lot of extra time and work

Comment: Write a method that returns you either human or alien based on the value of userclass

Comment: @Andrewsnowfall: But you had time to put them in variables? Just use find and replace, then.

Comment: @rynah Each variable is loaded from a config file. It's to complicated for me to explain without writing a novel. Lets just say it can be many different thing

Comment: @nitegazer2003 I was just thinking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use reflection to do it, although it might hurt the performance.

A better way is to use a `Enum` to represent the `userclass` instead of using a `String`.

Comment: How does an `Enum` get you any closer?

Comment: @rynah since it seems that the `userclass` has a pretty small number of legal values, OP can use `Enum` to either 1. implement a method on the enum to do whatever he wants 2. pass a enum to Cv to let it decide what it wants to do. Either way, it enforces something that using a `String` cannot.

Answer (score 0):

how about using class.forName :

```
Object o = Class.forName(userclass)
```

this assuming your userclass is a string.